# need to show tooltip over callout in Timeline chart

Tags: highcharts

Currently tooltip is coming both on bar and callout need to show it[tooltipovercallout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsNIM.png) tooltip over callout in Timeline chart

Comment: Please reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx68cd91/ 
in this link we can see when we move mouse over bar or respective label same tooltip sowing for those need to show tooltip on data label only.

Comment: I think that you should be able to achieve it by using the `tooltip.positioner` callback: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o3eaxjyn/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Comment: Can we show this tooltip when mouse over on callout boxes ?

Comment: as I can see, the tooltip appears while mouse over the data labels, could you explain more precisely what do you have in mind?

Comment: currently is is sowing when we are hovering mouse on bar also , but we need it only over data label(callout) hover.

Comment: Please take a look at this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7b92q0cg/